# Unity socket project don't work when installed to iPhone

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, sockets, unity-game-engine

My Unity project related with socket communication works fine on my Mac. I run a C# server on my own computer's terminal and then run the unity project. The unity project can connect to my server and receive the message sent by the server. Every thing works fine. However, when I Build and Run this unity project to my iPhone, it comes with some problems:

```
2016-12-26 12:43:43.915127 ProductName[8497:5717779] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful

2016-12-26 12:43:44.095512 ProductName[8497:5717642] -> registered mono modules 0xb94140
2016-12-26 12:43:44.646127 ProductName[8497:5717642] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
2016-12-26 12:43:44.810782 ProductName[8497:5717642] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2016-12-26 12:43:44.811680 ProductName[8497:5717642] Metal API Validation Enabled
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
Renderer: PowerVR SGX 543
Vendor:   Imagination Technologies
Version:  OpenGL ES 2.0 IMGSGX543-128
GLES:     2
GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_instanced_arrays GL_EXT_map_buffer_range GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_pvrtc_sRGB GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_APPLE_clip_distance GL_APPLE_color_buffer_packed_float GL_APPLE_copy_texture_levels GL_APPLE_framebuffer_multisample GL_APPLE_rgb_422 GL_APPLE_sync GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_max_level GL_APPLE_texture_packed_float GL_IMG_read_format GL_IMG_texture_comp

ression_pvrtc 
OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 2.0 graphics device ; Context level  <OpenGL ES 2.0> ; Context handle 392780752
Initialize engine version: 5.4.2f2 (b7e030c65c9b)
UnloadTime: 5.501916 ms
SocketException: Connection timed out
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean requireSocketPolicy) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPEndPoint remote_end_point) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPAddress[] ipAddresses, Int32 port) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)

Setting up 1 worker threads for Enlighten.
  Thread -> id: 40595000 -> priority: 1 
2016-12-26 12:45:01.391673 ProductName[8497:5717642] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction
2016-12-26 12:45:01.393101 ProductName[8497:5717642] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction
```

Because it works well on the computer, so I think the IP address is not the problem. Can anyone help? Here is the code for my server.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
            TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
            serverSocket.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> Server Started");
            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> Accept connection from client");
//          Console.ReadLine();

            while (true) {
                String textinput;
                textinput = Console.ReadLine ();
                NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream ();
                byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (textinput + "$");
                serverStream.Write (outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
                serverStream.Flush ();
            }

            clientSocket.Close();
            serverSocket.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the code for my unity project:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Client : MonoBehaviour {

    System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
    private Thread oThread;

    //  for UI update
    public GameObject updatetext;
    String tempMesg = "Waiting...";

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        updatetext.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Waiting...";
        clientSocket.Connect("10.132.198.29", 8888);
        oThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart (getInformation));
        oThread.Start ();
        Debug.Log ("Running the client");
    }

    void getInformation(){
        while (true) {
            try {
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream ();
                byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
                networkStream.Read (bytesFrom, 0, (int)bytesFrom.Length);
                string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString (bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring (0, dataFromClient.IndexOf ("$"));
                Debug.Log (" >> Data from Server - " + dataFromClient);

                tempMesg = dataFromClient;

                string serverResponse = "Last Message from Server" + dataFromClient;

                Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (serverResponse);
                networkStream.Write (sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                networkStream.Flush ();
                Debug.Log (" >> " + serverResponse);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Debug.Log ("Exception error:" + ex.ToString ());
                oThread.Abort ();
                oThread.Join ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I am wondering do I need to set something for enabling the socket plugin in Xcode?

Comment: @Programmer I am trying connect to a local ip address which is I use ipconfig to check it from my Mac terminal. Sorry, I don't have Android device... So I don't know whether it works on android or not...

Comment: @Programmer My iPhone is 5c, and the IOS version is 10.2. Thank you so much.

Comment: have you tried this? clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port); I think you need to Parse your "10.132.198.29" for connection.